# Using a Java For-Each Loop to iterate over an ArrayList which has private access?

Tags: java, class, foreach

I have three classes: Labradors, Kennels and Show.  The Kennel contains a private ArrayList of 
 Labradors. As shown:

Labradors.java:

```java
public class Labradors {
    private String name;
    private String description;

    public Labradors(String n, String d) {
        name = n;
        description = d;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Kennel.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Kennel{
    private ArrayList<Labradors> labs;

    public Kennel() {
        labs = new ArrayList<Labradors>();
    }

    public void addDog(Labradors l) {
        labs.add(l);
    }

}
```

and

Show.java

```
class Show
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Labradors Dave = new Labradors("Dave", "Good dog!");
        Labradors Bob = new Labradors("Bob", "Likes tummy rubs!");
        Kennel niceHome = new Kennel();
        niceHome.addDog(Dave);
        niceHome.addDog(Bob);


        for (Labradors lab: niceHome.labs ) {
            System.out.println(lab.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

My for-each loop in Show gives me the following error:

```sh
Show.java:12: error: labs has private access in Kennel
                for (Labradors lab: niceHome.labs ) {
                                            ^
1 error
```

Clearly one solution would be to make the ArrayList public, but my understanding of encapsulation is that best practice means it should be private and a Getter written.  But how do I do this?

I feel this should have a really easy answer, but I'm having difficulty tracking it down...

NB - I'm using openjdk version 11.0.6 on Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: You need to create an output method for your Kennel object. Private means that only that class can see it.  You're other option is to create a getter (getLabs()) that simply returns to list.

Comment: create getter `public ArrayList<Labradors> getLabradors() { return this.labs; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Kennel Class make a getter function

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Kennel{
    private ArrayList<Labradors> labs;

    public Kennel() {
        labs = new ArrayList<Labradors>();
    }

    public void addDog(Labradors l) {
        labs.add(l);
    }

    public ArrayList<Labradors> getLabs(){
        return this.labs;
    }
}
```

Then access from main function like this

```
class Show
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Labradors Dave = new Labradors("Dave", "Good dog!");
        Labradors Bob = new Labradors("Bob", "Likes tummy rubs!");
        Kennel niceHome = new Kennel();
        niceHome.addDog(Dave);
        niceHome.addDog(Bob);


        for (Labradors lab: niceHome.getLabs()) {
            System.out.println(lab.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had done so much googling I ended up thoroughly confused and thinking it was [bad practice to return a collection directly](https://refactoring.guru/encapsulate-collection), and instead you were meant to do something far more complex.  Which led to a whole new rabbit hole of searching.  Very happy to be wrong however, as this is the simple solution I was hoping for.